# how can I make my Python string match non-greedily?

Tags: python, string, string-matching

Given a text file that looks like so:

```
Samsung Galaxy S6 active SM-G890A 32GB Camo White (AT&T) *AS-IS* Cracked Screen
Samsung Galaxy S6 SM-G920 - 32GB - White Verizon Cracked screen
Samsung Galaxy S6 edge as is cracked screen
```

I've tried to think of a number of different ways to have the string `Samsung Galaxy S6` not match `Samsung Galaxy S6 edge`, but can't seem to come up with a way that works.  There's no point in the string where it's clear that the name of the phone has ended and the extraneous information begins, so splitting them up that way and comparing to a dictionary or something like that wouldn't work.

I tried to think of some way to write the following:

```
phones = ['Samsung Galaxy S6', 'Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge']
lines = open('phones.txt', 'r').readlines()
for line in lines:
    for phone in phones:
        if phone in line and no other phone in phones is in line:
            print('match found')
```

but I can't think of the right way to structure it - anyone have any ideas?  I'm sure that I'm missing something simple here, but just can't figure out what.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  Given the text file you said, what do you want to do?  Are you saying you are also given the string "Samsung Galaxy S6" and want to see which lines it matches?  Or that you want to extract the phone name from each line?

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead: [**`Samsung Galaxy S6(?! edge)`**](https://regex101.com/r/U6kKYZ/1)

Comment: `if sum(1 for phone in phones if phone in line) ==  1:` <-- checks if exactly one kind of phone is in the line.

Comment: @BrenBarn ideally I'd like to extract the phone name from each line from varying strings given a list of phone names.  The problem I'm running into is that strings like "Samsung Galaxy S6" are matching with lines "Samsung Galaxy S6", "Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge", etc.

Comment: You could also sort your list of phone names by length, with longer names first, so that when you match them in order you know that if one matches no longer one has matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start by sorting your phones so that it will look at them by length

```
phones.sort(key=len,reverse=True)
```

then break when you find a match

```
for phone in phones:
   if phone in line:
      print "FOUND:",repr(phone),"IN",repr(line)
      break # we dont need to keep looking for other phones in this line
```

maybe?

this way "Samsung Galaxy s6 Edge" comes before "Samsung Galaxy" in your checks and you will match the longest one... without requireing more knowledge of your phone list like the regex answer

Answer (score 3):

A negative lookahead will do:

```
Samsung Galaxy S6(?! edge)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/U6kKYZ/1).

Comment: great answer +1 ... although im reminded of a saying ... "something something, and now i have 2 problems" :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I know what you mean ... "now i have 2 problems - what to do with my freetime?"

Answer (score 1):

```
if sum(1 for phone in phones if phone in line) == 1:
```

This actually counts the members of `phones` that are also members of `line`.  Then we just check to make sure the number is one.

Comment: im not sure this actually does what OP wants...  he wants the best match i think ... he doesnt want to match "Samsung Galaxy" agains "Samsung Galaxy S6" (at least thats my interprettation) or not :P (I just saw OP's comment)

Comment: actually yeah, I was mistaken. @JoranBeasley is correct.